# pylint unused-variable error in global function which is used in other module

Tags: python, pylint

I run pylint (2.15.10) this way:

```
pylint --allow-global-unused-variables=no src/
```

I get errors like this:

```
************* Module builder.documentation
src\builder\documentation.py:582:0: W0612: Unused variable 'build_documentation' (unused-variable)
```

I have in that line this:

```
def build_documentation(folder: Path):
    ...
```

It's correct that `build_documentation()` function is not used in documentation.py file. However, other files in my project are using it, eg: in src\builder\builder.py file I have:

```
from documentation import build_documentation
...
        build_documentation(folder)
```

Comment: def build_documentationfolder

and 

build_documentation are not the same function, is it a copy paste mistake?

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake... I have edited the post to fix it. Thanks for raising it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `--allow-global-unused-variables=no` if you don't want pylint to warn you about API variable. The default has the correct behavior and this option is only here so you can detect those. See https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/919

Comment: Thank for your feedback! However, if I do so I cannot detect global variables that are not actually used in my code. Is there any why to run pylint to detect that?

Comment: Can you differentiate API vs unused global variable without knowing what the API is because you made the code ? I don't think that's possible even theoretically.